# React Navigation - why navigation bar is appearing below header but not at the bottom

Tags: react-native, bottomnavigationview

This is the container file.
Here I have defined all the required details for the bottom navigation and it is rendered at the top the screen but it should be render at the bottom of the screen.

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import MaterialCommunityIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";

import HomeScreen from "./Fragments/HomeScreen";
import WalletScreen from "./Fragments/WalletScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "./Fragments/ProfileScreen";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

import { Platform } from "react-native";
export const tabBarHeight = Platform.OS === "ios" ? 60 : 45;
function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#03dbfc",
            height: tabBarHeight,
          },
          tabBarActiveTintColor: "white",
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Home",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Wallet"
          component={WalletScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Wallet",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="wallet" color={color} size={size} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={ProfileScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Profile",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="face" color={color} size={size} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default MyTabs;
```

I can't see the content of each screen or fragment.

Home.js

```
import { Text } from "react-native";

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return <Text>Home</Text>;
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Profile.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";

const ProfileScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return <Text>Profile</Text>;
};

export default ProfileScreen;
```

Wallet.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";

const WalletScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return <Text>Wallet</Text>;
};

export default WalletScreen;
```

[image]

Please answer this question I am new to react-native.

App.js

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
import BottomNavigation from "./components/BottomNavigation/BottomNavigation";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Header title="ApnaPayment" />
      <BottomNavigation />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Might not help but try `<View style={{flex:1}}>`

Comment: @carlosdafield I believe you are saying that wrap container in View, then apply this style, right?
But it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens because the `View` on `App.js` shrinks the page content. You don't need to create a header component, the `react-navigation` provides it for you. I suggest you remove the header component on `App.js` and add the header title as a screen option on your navigator. Another tip is you don't need to define the height of the tabs, the `react-navigation` provides it too by default. Follow the example code below.

File with your navigator:

```js
// Some code above...

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#03dbfc",
          },
          tabBarActiveTintColor: "white",
          title: "ApnaPayment",
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Home",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Wallet"
          component={WalletScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Wallet",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="wallet" color={color} size={size} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={ProfileScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Profile",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="face" color={color} size={size} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default MyTabs;
```

Your App.js:

```js
// Some code above...

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BottomNavigation />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I use an image as the title?

Comment: Yes, just add the image as a component on `headerTitle` as an option. You can see the [example in the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers#replacing-the-title-with-a-custom-component).